# UITableView inside a UICollectionView: can't set value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with 4 UICollectionViewCells. Each cell contains a UITableView with a varying number of cells.

I have an array from which I need to pass a value (depending on the indexPath) into the cell. My problem is that it always gives me nil when I try to do this.

So for example I have this array:

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
```

I have this code in my collection view's cellForItemAt method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell

    cell.myString = arrayOfStrings[indexPath.row]

    cell.label.text = "This text is set."
    return cell
}
```

The cell's label is set properly, but when I try to print myString in the cell's table view's cellForRowAt method it always returns nil.
I need the string because I plan to manipulate the table views depending on the string passed in.

So why is this happening and what can be done?

Comment: did you check the indexPath.row value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
extension HomeViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return 4
   }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DealTableViewCell
    cell.DealCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.DealCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.DealCollectionView.tag = 10101
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BusinessTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessTableViewCell
    cell.BusinessCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.BusinessCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.BusinessCollectionView.tag = 10102
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 2 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
    cell.FilterCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.FilterCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.FilterCollectionView.tag = 10103
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ComboTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ComboTableViewCell
    cell.ComboCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.ComboCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.ComboCollectionView.tag = 10104
    return cell
   }
  }
}
```

Add the collection view to each tableview cell and set delegate in tableview cell

```
   extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if collectionView.tag == 10101 {
    return 3
  } else if collectionView.tag == 10102 {
    return 3
  } else if collectionView.tag == 10103 {
    return 3
  } else if collectionView.tag == 10104 {
    return 3
 }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView.tag == 10101 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DealCollectionViewCell

    return cell
} else if collectionView.tag == 10102 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BusinessCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessCollectionViewCell

    return cell
} else if collectionView.tag == 10103 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCollectionViewCell

    return cell
} else if collectionView.tag == 10104 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ComboCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ComboCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}

return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

For reload the collectionView in use

```
if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? 
tableViewCell {
  cell.collectionView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: but am used like UiCollectionView within UITableView

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I made my CollectionViewCell the delegate and data source, not the ViewController. Changing that was enough to avoid getting nil. However, now my problem is that for the first table view it prints "test2" (it should print test1). When I swipe through the collection view and back to the first cell it now prints "test1".

Comment: Solved it! Just needed to call cell.layoutIfNeeded() before returning the collection view cell.